# Split into trainset and testset with a string with an input

Tags: python, prediction, training-data

I´m really new in python's world. 
I have allready seen an example of an splitting in trainset and testset. But only with numeric type. The example:

```
import random

with open("datafile.txt", "rb") as f:
    data = f.read().split('\n')

random.shuffle(data)

train_data = data[:50]
test_data = data[50:]
```

So what I want to do is to split the data into training or testset by a regular/relative expression. To do it with an input. Imagine that i have a column with all the fruits,another with his weight, and another with his price,, but some of then don´t have price. I want to split the data for example for apples with the price>0 to do the trainset, and the apples with price 0 to the test set to do some predictions.

And i want  to do it, with a dataset, and i have to input what I want to predict

Sorry if i don't explained it well.

And thank you for your help, any advice would be apreciated.

The data could be something like this

```
Fruits     Weight   Price
Apple       5         1
Apple       3         0.6
Apple       3         0
Banana      5         10
Banana      4         8
Banana      2         0 
Orange      10        20
Orange      5         12
Orange      2         0
Kiwi        5         6
Kiwi        5         6
Kiwi        2         0
```

Then i want to input like Fruit: Apple , Weight: 10
And the output want to be the price after doing the training.

Thank you again for the help !!!

Comment: learn numpy and boolean indexing

Comment: *if i don't explained it well* - it would better if you posted the input sample and the final expected output

Answer (score 1):

Use pandas for that and numpy:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_table('datafile.txt', sep='\s+', header=None)
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
print(df)


print(df.reindex(np.random.permutation(df.index)))
```

The output of the first `print` is:

```
        0     1
0   apple  10.0
1  banana   4.0
2  orange   2.0
3   peach   0.0
```

After using the `permutation` function of numpy, the `DataFrame` looks like this:

```
        0     1
2  orange   2.0
0   apple  10.0
1  banana   4.0
3   peach   0.0
```

If you want to get the first column of the data, use `df[0]` and the second column can be accessed accordingly: `df[1]`. Both are basically numpy lists. With that data, you can do your training and testing thing. I hope that this is of help for you. Due to the fairly unspecific question, this is all I can do.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you want to split the data to make predictions, based on a logic where train set will have fruits with price > 0 while test set will have fruits with 0 price. If you try to build any prediction model I STRONGLY advise AGAINST that ,because your model will have prediction bias.

For example if you train a logistic regression model with this logic you will always overestimate the price in test set because your training set has positive values only. Train and test set should have equal marginal probabilities for all classes.

That being said after you end up with the dataset you want to split you can try [sklearn.train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) for the split. For example

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#Create 5x4 table with the last column to be regarded as target value
data = np.arange(20).reshape(5, 4)

#Split into training/test for features(X) and target variable(y)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data[:,0:3],
data[:,3], test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```